# why is my selector inside media query not working

Tags: html, css

the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cloud-zsnss?file=/src/styles.css:937-1010

in the css file I have a media query that targets any device which has a width under 500px

```css
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

However it didn't have any effects on the

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
```

A couple people are saying it is working fine. I have attached a screenshot to show that it is in fact not working.
[image]

I cannot figure out where it went wrong.

Another question is, what is the different between

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
}
```

and

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
}
```

I have seen both in examples of media queries.

Comment: I've just checked your link. Your media query works fine, it has effect.

Comment: As @DanielSixl said, your link works as expected. For the second question, there is no difference.

Comment: @disinfor not it is not working. Please open the console and inspect the `.wrapper` you will see it is not being applied with the css. I have attached the screenshot to show that

Comment: @DanielSixl It is NOT working. Please open the console and inspect the `.wrapper` you will see it is not being applied with the css. I have attached the screenshot to show that

Comment: If I got what you mean Its content size should be changed not wrapper.

Comment: Check if your html code has viewport meta...

Comment: The difference is in Mobile- vs Desktop-View in your Inspector. Try switching between both settings. I think Quentin's answer makes it clear.

Comment: @Joji I did open my console and look at it: https://imgur.com/a/QEOW7ah

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: @Joji Mobile vs Desktop: https://imgur.com/a/Z6lLfC8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media query doesn't apply because the effective browser width is not small enough.

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

… to the `<head>`.

Without it mobile browsers (and tools which simulate them) will assume the design is intended for desktop browsers only and will zoom out to simulate having a desktop width screen.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for further reading.